# How should i update a for loop tic tac toe grid to complete the programme without array n repetitive structure?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

```
String GameString ="123456789";
//3x3 grid
For (int i =0; i<9;i++){
    System.out.print(gameString.charAt(i));
    If(i!=8) {
        System.out.println("\n---------");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("l")
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Above shows the grid structure.
-n
Must use for, while and do-while

Comment: `javascript !== java`

Comment: Here is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/). And there is [Java](https://www.java.com/en/).